# Capturing oozie logs and customize them

Tags: logging, hive, log4j, oozie, error-logging

I'm working with the oozie workflow logs.

To customize these, like change the location where the logs are pumped or what exactly to log, where should I make changes to reflect them for my workflow?

Should I change the oozie-log4j.properties or change it specific to the action like hive-log4j.properties, sqoop-log4j.peoperties?

I'm basically trying to differentiate between the workflow logs and the application logs and trying to monitor workflow logs.